# Command to auto-update apt sources.list in Debian

Tags: debian, apt

Is there a command in Debian that I can run that will update my sources.list file to the best possible servers?

I maintain a number of Debian servers, and I've found one of the mirrors has gone away.  I'd rather not have to go to each server and manually modify the sources.list file. It would be great if there was a command I could run that would cause my server to go out into the world, find the geographically closest or the fastest mirrors, and build a new sources.list file.

Comment: netselect-apt - speed tester for choosing a fast Debian mirror

Comment: @MarkWagner That looks to be exactly what I want.  Please add it as an answer so I can accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

netselect-apt - speed tester for choosing a fast Debian mirror

Comment: Just a note for posterity - netselect-apt also generates a sources.list file from its findings.